# Eclipse RCP Main window not resizable

Tags: eclipse-rcp, window-resize

does anyone know how to disable the possibility of resizing the main window of my Eclipse application

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a restrictive ShellStyle, as suggested in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg32276.html) and detailed [in this one](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg64611.html) (**`SWT.DIALOG_TRIM`**):

```
public void preWindowOpen() {
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(800, 600));
        configurer.setShowCoolBar(false);
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(false);
        configurer.setTitle("RFID demo");


}
```

> > You need to call `setShellStyle()`. See the Javadoc for the Shell(int) constructor for an explanation of how to form the argument.
> >     According to `WorkbenchWindowConfigurer` the default value is `SWT.SHELL_TRIM`, which includes the `SWT.RESIZE` option.
> >     You'll have to formulate a value that does not include `SWT.RESIZE`.
>
> It was exactly what I was searching for,

```
configurer.setShellStyle(SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
```

Comment: It doesn't clear where to put setShellStyle. Tried to put under setTitle - doesn't work